# Pivot table for ASP.Net pages

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dataset, pivot-table

I want to create an Excel pivot table using data table and dataset using ASP.net. I have made a test and it works fine in my local computer. It takes data from datasource, load it to Excel and then creates pivot table but when I host it on the server it is not working and it event do not give any error so I am able to find the problem. Can anybody help me please with this issue?